# What application can I build to stress-test real-time communication in a multi-user environment?

Tags: real-time

As a main project in 5th semester of CS degree I am doing a research on technologies for realizing real-time server2client communication in a multi-user environment. The deciding factors are:
 **1. Performance 

 2. Scalability**
 3. Ease of implementation
 4. Portability
 5. Architectural flexibility
 6. Community support 
 7. Licensing fees

Now, I could build a chat application with each technology, which I analyze, and get it over with. The problem is that I don't think that such an app would even remotely reach the boundaries of what a certain technology can do.

So my question is: what kind of prototype application could I build to make a good test for Performance and Scalability?

If it's any help, the technologies which I am going to test are: SignalR, Pusher, Pubnub, LightStreamer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not a "popular" answer, although:

My experience shows me that each and every case is special.
There is not `prototype application` for that, except for `generic tools` like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) (generic to some degree, uh).

For each test you simply have to get the right "ingredients".